# Amazon connect custom CCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-connect

I'm trying to create a Amazon connect custom CCP by following a AWS workshop tutorial,
I've followed each steps, in the end unable to connect custom ccp with the amazon connect control panel

I've tried the workshop on custom ccp by AWS:
[AWS Connect custom CCP](https://explore.skillbuilder.aws/learn/course/432/play/1251/amazon-connect-build-a-custom-call-control-panel)
I've followed each steps, in the end when I opened the ccp.html url from s3 bucket I'm able to open the custom ccp but could not link it with the amazon connect control panel
[custom ccp ui opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULvZC.png).
when i open the files from console :
[opened ccpcourse.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxgTr.png)
this are the network log:
[network log 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98gMQ.png)
[network log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDvus.png)

to remove the access error i tried this :
[access error solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZiirF7ap5U&t=203s)
and added this to bucket policy :
`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*" Also With "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

`
but the problem is still there, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

must allow public access to objects in S3, modified ACLs

And when you add a new element you must allow public access

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MWyK.png)

[OBJETOS PUBLICOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ2HY.png)

[ACL READ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imdji.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cb3y.png)